# Emacs -- creating a custom highlight parentheses function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, *further* modifying the following *already modified* excerpt from the `highlight-parentheses` library:  https://github.com/nschum/highlight-parentheses.el [Fn 1.]

**GOAL**:  The **goal** is to use something like `mapcar` or `dolist` to automatically replace `INSERT-FACE-HERE` with a *different* face from the variable `my-parens-faces` *each time* `while` *does a loop*.  The visual effect will be a rainbow coloring of parentheses based on the level of nesting.

I am removing the overlays with a `post-command-hook` and a function similar to `remove-overlays`, and then subsequently adding new overlays with the `parens` function below.  I will not be *moving* any overlays -- just creating and deleting.  The final version will use variables for the faces and target specific overlays for removal, but here is a sample of what it will look like:  `(add-hook 'post-command-hook (lambda () (remove-overlays) (parens)))`

Each time `while` does a loop, I want to insert a different face from the variable `my-parens-faces` -- going in order, like `dolist`.  For example:

- `while` doing loop # 1:  `(:foreground "black" :background "cyan")`
- `while` doing loop # 2:  `(:foreground "blue" :background "purple")`
- `while` doing loop # 3:  `(:foreground "green" :background "blue")`
- `while` doing loop # 4:  `(:foreground "yellow" :background "purple")`
- `while` doing loop # 5:  `(:foreground "orange" :background "yellow")`
- `while` doing loop # 6:  `(:foreground "red" :background "green")`
- `while` doing loop # 7:  `(:foreground "pink" :background "brown")`
- `while` doing loop # 8:  `(:foreground "blue" :background "beige")`

```lisp
(defun parens ()
  (let* (pos1 pos2)
    (save-excursion
      (condition-case err
        (while (setq pos1 (cadr (syntax-ppss pos1)))
          (overlay-put (make-overlay pos1 (1+ pos1)) 'face 'INSERT-FACE-HERE)
          (when (setq pos2 (scan-sexps pos1 1))
            (overlay-put (make-overlay (1- pos2) pos2) 'face 'INSERT-FACE-HERE)))
        (error nil)) )))

(defvar my-parens-faces '(
  (:foreground "black" :background "cyan")
  (:foreground "blue" :background "purple")
  (:foreground "green" :background "blue")
  (:foreground "yellow" :background "purple")
  (:foreground "orange" :background "yellow")
  (:foreground "red" :background "green")
  (:foreground "pink" :background "brown")
  (:foreground "blue" :background "beige")))
```

[*Footnote number 1*:   Reference to the *highlight-parentheses* library is *not* needed to answer this question, but the reference is being included so that proper attribute is made to the author (i.e., Nikolaj Schumacher) who inspired the `parens` function in this question.]

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use [`rainbow-delimiters-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters)?

Comment: @Justin Wood -- I am writing an unrelated custom minor-mode that gets interfered with by having miscellaneous overlay objects laying around as a result of using the function `move-overlay` instead of deleting overlays.  The above-function named `parens` works, it just needs a `dolist` added -- however, I get confused when dealing with `while` and `dolist` and am not sure how to handle it.  I am eliminating conflicts in my minor-mode by building into it only the basic functions that I need -- in this case, `parens` will meet my needs once I understand how to use `dolist` and `while` together.

Comment: @lawlist Your minor mode gets confused by *arbitrary overlays*?! And why is that specifically caused by `move-overlay`?  Can't you just change your minor mode to only work on overlays that it created itself?

Comment: @lunaryorn -- There are two likely suspects.  With the library `highlight-parentheses`, multiple overlay objects are being created at `point-min` and they accumulate with each successive run of the `post-command-hook` -- that incrementally slows down my unrelated function which places overlays from `window-start` to `window-end`.  The second likely suspect is when `make-overlay` is executed at a `point` other than `overlay-put`, making complete removal of that overlay problematic.  Removing, instead of moving, works well; and so does executing `make-overlay` in tandem with `overlay-put`.

Comment: @lawlist I do not see any striking reason for why any of that should conflict with overlays from another library such as rainbow delimiters.

Comment: @lunaryorn -- Rainbow delimiters does not appear to use overlays, and relies upon font-lock instead.  There is another slight slow down issue in my overlay function that is corrected by temporarily turning off font-lock-mode and then turning it on again once the overlays are placed.  I would prefer to use my own `parens` function, rather than incorporate Rainbow Delimiters (which would could raise new time-consuming issues that I haven't dealt with yet).  This morning, I will write a `counter` and conditions for the `parens` function -- i.e., when `while` loop `(= i 1)`, then black and cyan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(defvar parens-mode-command-exclusions '(mwheel-scroll scroll-up scroll-down)
  "List of functions that are excluded from triggering the function `parens'.")

(defvar parens-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    st)
  "Syntax table used while executing the function `parens'.")

(defgroup parens nil
  "Faces for highlighting parentheses in `parens-mode'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-one-face
  '((t (:foreground "magenta")))
  "Face for `parens-one-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-two-face
  '((t (:foreground "red")))
  "Face for `parens-two-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-three-face
  '((t (:foreground "yellow")))
  "Face for `parens-three-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-four-face
  '((t (:foreground "green")))
  "Face for `parens-four-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-five-face
  '((t (:foreground "cyan")))
  "Face for `parens-five-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-six-face
  '((t (:foreground "orange")))
  "Face for `parens-six-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-seven-face
  '((t (:foreground "purple")))
  "Face for `parens-seven-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-eight-face
  '((t (:foreground "blue")))
  "Face for `parens-eight-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-nine-face
  '((t (:foreground "brown")))
  "Face for `parens-nine-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defface parens-ten-face
  '((t (:foreground "white")))
  "Face for `parens-ten-face'."
  :group 'parens)

(defvar parens-overlays-exist-p nil
"Simple test to see whether the parens overlays have been placed.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'parens-overlays-exist-p)

(defun parens ()
"Portions of this function were borrowed from the library
`highlight-parentheses` written by Nikolaj Schumacher.
https://github.com/nschum/highlight-parentheses.el"
  (unless (memq this-command parens-mode-command-exclusions)
    (with-syntax-table parens-mode-syntax-table
      (let* (
          (pt (point))
          (pos1 (if
                  (or
                    (= pt (point-min))
                    (eq (preceding-char) 40) ;; open-parentheses
                    (eq (preceding-char) 91) ;; open-squre-bracket
                    (eq (preceding-char) 123)) ;; open-wavy-bracket
              pt
              (1- pt)))
          pos2
          selected-face
          (i 0) )
        (remove-parens-overlays)
        (save-excursion
          (condition-case nil
            (while (setq pos1 (cadr (syntax-ppss pos1)))
              (if (= i 10)
                (setq i 1)
                (setq i (1+ i)))
              (cond
                ((= i 1)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-one-face))
                ((= i 2)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-two-face))
                ((= i 3)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-three-face))
                ((= i 4)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-four-face))
                ((= i 5)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-five-face))
                ((= i 6)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-six-face))
                ((= i 7)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-seven-face))
                ((= i 8)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-eight-face))
                ((= i 9)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-nine-face))
                ((= i 10)
                  (setq selected-face 'parens-ten-face)) )
              (overlay-put (make-overlay pos1 (1+ pos1)) 'face selected-face)
              (when (setq pos2 (scan-sexps pos1 1))
                (overlay-put (make-overlay (1- pos2) pos2) 'face selected-face)))
            (error nil) ))
        (setq parens-overlays-exist-p t)))))

(defun remove-parens-overlays ()
  (when parens-overlays-exist-p
    (dolist (face '(
        parens-one-face
        parens-two-face
        parens-three-face
        parens-four-face
        parens-five-face
        parens-six-face
        parens-seven-face
        parens-eight-face
        parens-nine-face
        parens-ten-face))
      (remove-overlays nil nil 'face face)) 
    (setq parens-overlays-exist-p nil)))

(defun turn-off-parens-mode ()
  (parens-mode -1))

(define-minor-mode parens-mode
"A minor-mode for highlighting parentheses."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " ‹›"
  :keymap nil
  :global nil
  :group 'parens
  (cond
    (parens-mode
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'parens t t)
      (add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook 'turn-off-parens-mode nil t)
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Turned ON `parens-mode`.")))
    (t
      (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'parens t)
      (remove-hook 'change-major-mode-hook 'turn-off-parens-mode t)
      (remove-parens-overlays)
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Turned OFF `parens-mode`.")))))
```