# How to properly locate unbalanced parenthesis in source code?

Tags: c, emacs, syntax

Recently I learned some text editor has functions to check whether all parentheses are balanced inside a file. (e.g. check-parens in Emacs). It may even be able to highlight the 1st unbalanced parenthesis if there is any. However I am not clear whether there is a way to properly locate it instead of always highlight the 1st unbalanced occurrence.

Consider below code:

```
void foo()
{
  int some_num0 = 0;
  {
    int some_num1 = 1;
    {
      int some_num2 = 2;
      { 
        int some_num3 = 3;  
        //ops I forgot to close this block.
    }   
  }
}
```

A simple balance check, (e.g. check-parens in Emacs) will bring me to the opening brace of `foo`'s definition. However a more reasonable indication should bring me to somewhere around the innermost level, the one near some_num3. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you specifically looking to do this only in Emacs? Do you want to write your own script for it, or are you asking if there's something built-in? Or are you asking  more generally what an algorithm for this task would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the popular Emacs libraries include, but are not limited to:

- highlight-parentheses:  https://github.com/nschum/highlight-parentheses.el
- rainbow-delimiters:  https://github.com/jlr/rainbow-delimiters

Here is a link to a recent modification that I made to one of the functions used by highlight-parentheses, which will preserve the overlays when using `scroll-up`, `scroll-down`, or `mwheel-scroll`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269210/2112489

Here is a link to a modified version of highlight-parentheses, which is what I use:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23998965/2112489  I have not yet updated the posted version of `parens-mode` to include the modification for scrolling that is referred to in the previous link.  My personal preference is to add / delete overlays, instead of storing them at the beginning of the buffer and moving them around.

Here is a screen-shot of a modified version of highlight-parentheses:

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/parens_mode_example.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The parenthesis check basically reads the code and updates a counter whenever it hits a parenthesis. If it is an opening bracket, it adds 1 ; if it is a closing one, it adds -1 (subtracts 1). If the counter ever hits a negative number, there is a problem, and it tells you. If, at the end of the code, the counter is not zero, there also is a problem ; that is your case.

But how do you want it to know where the missing brace(s) actually is/are ? The only way to do something close to what you want is to check for the indentation as well. But what if your code is not properly indented ?

I do not know of any tool that checks for indentation while checking braces, and I doubt there is a good one (if any).

The fact is, the more you forget a parenthesis, and above all, the more you write code, the more you remember to *not forget* these parenthesis. Or at least, it is likely to happen.

So, do not blame your IDE for not being endowed with reason, but rather blame you for not immediately locating missing brackets. And write code.

Comment: Nice comment. I asked this because I usually had to do peer check of some spaghetti code assigned to me, or in the middle of pair programming.

Comment: For myself I rarely has a missing-parentheses issue. I always add them ATOMiccally - I add them by pairs and then start content insertion.

Comment: Oh, I now better understand your need. Your code comment `//ops I forgot to close this block.` led me to thinking that you were the one forgetting some brackets. Anyway, good luck with your spaghetti code then.

Answer (score 0):

If you indented all of the closing braces by one level, would you still say that it would be more reasonable to indicate the 4th opening brace?

If not, perhaps it should be checking for consistent indentation too.

Answer (score 0):

Not realy a `check-parens` solution but when something like this happens to me I usually mark the whole block and go `M-x indent-region` to have emacs try to indent the selected region correctly.

In your simple case it would indent them all one level (MRABs answer) and you would just close the last brace.

In a more complicated case indentation will break somewhere (i.e the code won't look like you expect it to do) and that is usually where the parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I just used notepad++ with the BracketsCheck plugin https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14090/best-way-to-find-unmatched-parentheses/2. After some hours searching and trying VSCode plugins, n++ did it for me :) I was checking a 2.5K lines XML file with about 270 formula expressions. Checking parenthesis formula by formula using the usual matching parenthesis highlighting feature wasn't looking much of an option.