# Show Parentheses When Inside Them - Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, paredit

In emacs there is a mode `show-paren-mode` which colors the opposite matching parenthesis when the cursor is on the other. I wrote an example explaining `show-paren-mode`:

```
( <-colored  colored-> )| <-cursor
```

However it does not work when the cursor is not on the parenthesis:

```
( <-not colored    cursor inside->|    not colored-> )
```

How can I enable this? I find that when performing slurpage and barfage in paredit I cannot keep track of the parentheses very well because they are not colored unless I am on them.

This is optimal:

```
( <-colored    cursor inside->|    colored-> )
```

Edit: Thanks to the comment by @lawlist I have resolved this issue.

Comment: I use `show-paren-mode` with `paredit-mode`. It shows the matching paren just like normal. Can you clarify what you are looking for with the interact between the two?

Comment: @verdammelt I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Consider using a library that is not dependent upon anything mentioned in your question and turn off the default `show-parens-mode` -- i.e., it doesn't matter if your eating/barfing/sluping/paredit/etc.  Take a look at highlight-parentheses:  https://github.com/tsdh/highlight-parentheses.el  Take a look at rainbow-delimiters:  https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters  And here is a link to my own spin on `highlight-parentheses`, which I like better (for a few important reasons, such as scrolling and not accumulating unnecessary overlays . . .):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23998965/2112489

Comment: `hl-sexp-mode` might be sufficient for your needs

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the reply, the one from your other stack overflow answer works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by [lawlist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112489/lawlist) I have added the [code from his answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985602/emacs-creating-a-custom-highlight-parentheses-function/23998965#23998965) into my init file.

It colors each set of matching parentheses in a rainbow pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me (more recent Emacs version (than 25?) may be required for the new advice implementation):

```
(define-advice show-paren-function (:around (fn) fix)
  "Highlight enclosing parens."
  (cond ((looking-at-p "\\s(") (funcall fn))
        (t (save-excursion
             (ignore-errors (backward-up-list))
             (funcall fn)))))
```